# VSCode Flutter - Change Available Devices

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

So I'm using Flutter in VSCode and I want to run my application in a web browser. However, the only web browser available is the Edge browser. I do not want the edge, I want to use the Brave browser. How do I change this? See image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1261.png)

I tried to go to Settings>Dart>DevTools>DevTools Browser>Selected "default" browser, since Brave is my default browser, but Edge still pops up in the available devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can access your localhost within the Brave browser using the following steps:

Firstly, navigate to your project directory in the terminal and execute the following command:

```
> flutter run -d web-server
```

After running this command, you'll receive the localhost path in the result. Here's an example:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Web Server in debug mode...
Waiting for connection from debug service on Web Server... 30.9s
lib\main.dart is being served at **http://localhost:52037** 
The web-server device requires the Dart Debug Chrome extension for debugging. Consider using the Chrome or Edge devices for an improved development workflow.
```

Finally, you can access the local server in your Brave browser by typing the following URL:

```
http://localhost:52037
```